# Additional Drivers for Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, additional-drivers, 17.10

The **Additional Drivers** settings interface is no longer available in Ubuntu 17.10

How can I install proprietary drivers in Ubuntu 17.10?

I need drivers for Wifi & Bluetooth (BCM43142) and Intel Graphics.

The earlier **Additional Drivers** program showed a package named `jockey` but it no longer seem to exist in repositories.

Comment: What driver you want to install ? Please [edit] your question, and add more infomation regarding the issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok I found it, it is hidden under Software & Updates.

[image]

Another way to install drivers is:

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

EDIT:

Additional Drivers program is now available in Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: On the command line, it is: 

sudo software-properties-gtk